# 手の姿勢推定における学習データのラベル付け

Tags: 機械学習

現在単視点RGB画像から手の姿勢推定を行いたくて、機械学習でやろうと思っています。
関節の位置をラベルとしてつけるイメージです。
このラベルなのですが、配列は学習データとして取り入れられるのでしょうか？
出力は推定される関節の位置で、これを手モデルに合成できればいいかなと思います。

機械学習の経験が浅く、どう学習データを作るのかがわかりません。ご教授頂けると幸いです。

---

追記 (具体的な方法): ボールを握っているような状況の手を、その中心(この場合は透明なボールの中心)から写します。モーションキャプチャーで撮影し‌​たものを用いるので、関節や手の甲の3次元‌​位置はわかっています。これを学習データの‌​ラベルとして、CNNなどの既存のネットワ‌​ークにかけられれば良いかなと思っています‌​。入力は画像のみ、出力は推定される関節や‌​手の甲の3次元位置をまとめた配列で出す、‌​のが具体的な手法のイメージです。クラスに‌​分類、というのは調べると見かけますが、回‌​帰的なものの参考資料はなかなかないですね‌​..。

Comment: 「機械学習」にも色々あります。まず、具体的にどういう手法で行おうとしていますか？

Comment: ボールを握っているような状況の手を、その中心(この場合は透明なボールの中心)から写します。モーションキャプチャーで撮影したものを用いるので、関節や手の甲の3次元位置はわかっています。これを学習データのラベルとして、CNNなどの既存のネットワークにかけられれば良いかなと思っています。入力は画像のみ、出力は推定される関節や手の甲の3次元位置をまとめた配列で出す、のが具体的な手法のイメージです。クラスに分類、というのは調べると見かけますが、回帰的なものの参考資料はなかなかないですね..。

Comment: とすると成果物の大体のイメージは [OpenPose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose) の「手」のみバージョンで、3D pose estimation までできると良い、みたいな感じでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: Christian Zimmermann & Thomas Brox. "Learning to Estimate 3D Hand Pose from Single RGB Images" (ICCV 2017) https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/projects/hand3d/

Comment: 参考: [Awesome Works on Hand Pose Estimation](https://github.com/xinghaochen/awesome-hand-pose-estimation)

Comment: それらにも目を通しましたが、デプスマップが必要であるのと、あくまで画像上の座標を取り出してるだけなので、自分の出したい、3次元位置とは少し違うのかなと思いました。自分の理解が追いついていないのもありますが。3d pose estimationは別途別のソフトで、指の関節などの3次元位置から推測する処理ができますので、あくまで、3次元位置の配列が出せればいいかなと思っています。やはり難しいでしょうか？

Comment: 上に挙げた Z&B の論文や OpenPose では共にデプスは必要ないと思います。OpenPose は初めは画像上の座標だけでしたが、今は3次元位置も推定できるようになっています。また、Z&B の研究は Theodore さんの問題設定と似ていると思ったのでリンクしてみたのですが、如何でしょうか？ 入力はRGBの画像1枚で出力は手のキーポイントたちの3次元座標、訓練時に必要なのは手の3次元座標でアノテートされたRGB画像です。

Comment: なるほど、よく見ると学習ではデプスマップ使ってないんですね。かなり‌​参考になります。結構ありがちなネタだと思‌​っていましたが、新しいんですね。アノテート、という表現がいまいちわからないのですが、RGB画像にうつる手の特徴点の単純なリストアップ、ということでしょうか。

Comment: はい、ネタとしてはありがちだと思います。たまたま新しい論文が見つかったので参照してみました。　／　「手の3次元座標でアノテートされたRGB画像」は、もう少し噛み砕くと「手の3次元座標情報が付いたRGB画像」という感じです。

Comment: 画像上でのキーポイントの位置、マスク画像を加えて用意しなければいけなさそうですが、期限まで時間がなく今からするのは不可能です・・。なんとかこのコードからこれらの要素を抜き出すことは可能なのでしょうか。

Comment: 「このコード」とはどういう意味でしょうか？　なお、 Z&B のものは論文やホームページ上に用いたデータセットの所在について書いてあります。

Comment: Z＆Bがアップしているコードを参照するとネットワークとして３段階あり、手を検出するネットワーク→キーポイントの画像上での位置を推定するネットワーク→画像上での位置から3次元座標を推定するという流れなので、やり口としては似て非なると思いました。

Comment: うーん、上手く理解できません。だんだん元のご質問から内容が離れてきたように思うので、一度内容を整理し、新しい質問として投稿して頂けませんか？

Comment: コード=ソースコードはわかっていただけていますか？話を一般化しようと思い、新しく質問を投稿しました。

Comment: はい。（スタック・オーバーフローのコメント欄はチャット的に用いるところではないので、やはり新しい質問として投稿頂くのが良いように思います）

Comment: 参考: 上の流れで投稿された質問です。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40111/19110

Answer (score 1):

「ラベル」という言葉の使い方が妙な気もしますが、結論から言うと可能です。

具体的な手法は、たとえば ICCV 2017 に出された Christian Zimmermann & Thomas Brox. ["Learning to Estimate 3D Hand Pose from Single RGB Images"](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/projects/hand3d/) が参考になると思います。

手の姿勢推定という研究は色々と行われているので、他の研究をまとめたサイトも存在しています。
https://github.com/xinghaochen/awesome-hand-pose-estimation