# 機械学習による配列の推定

Tags: 機械学習

人物が写っている画像からその人の年齢を推定するというものがあり、ラベル付けしていればRGB画像から値を推定することはできると思いますが、配列（例えば身長体重）を推定したい場合、この延長線上で実装はできるのでしょうか？

Comment: この内容だと、たとえば推論器を横に2つ並べて個別に身長と体重を推定させるようにすれば自明に "配列" に対する推論ができてしまうように思います（もちろんそういうことをおっしゃりたい訳では無いですよね）。何か前提としている実装方法やアルゴリズムがあるのではないでしょうか。そのあたりを具体的に追記して下さいませんか。

Comment: 学習データ:手のシルエット画像+手の関節の3次元位置をまとめた配列、入力:手のシルエット画像、出力:手の関節の3次元位置をまとめた配列、です。推論器を何十個と用意するのは時間かかりますか？